# ShinobiCharts crashing with "Can't form range" error

Tags: ios, swift, plot, charts, shinobi

I've followed the tutorial under to implement my trial-version of ShinobiCharts in my Swift-app. It all compiles but when I run the app I get this runtime error saying:

> fatal error: Can't form Range with end < start (lldb)

And the errors seem to be coming from:

```
SChart_License decryptAndCheckExpiryDate:outLicenseBase64:
SChart_License verifyKey:nilKeyMessage:
SChart_License verifyKey:
SChartCanvas drawChart:
SChartCanvasRenderView drawRect:
UIView(CALayerDelegate) drawLayer:inContext:
```

And obviously I'm just starting out in ShinobiCharts so I don't know what to make of this.

Please help me solving this issue.

Comment: You must be declaring a range somewhere, or giving two values that are intended to be used as a range. Print out the two values before calling it. Make sure that the first one is smaller than the second one, because ranges must be created in increasing order.

Comment: @erdekhayser Okay, thank you for that information, but I also realized I had not given up a license key, and now I do not know where to find it, do you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you forget to set a `licenseKey` on the chart, or globally on the `ShinobiCharts` class then you may get that error.

If you've downloaded a trial, then you'll have been emailed a license key. It's a very long string, and should be attached as a text file to the welcome email.